# remove/disable MobileFirst app "Server Connectivity Settings" from iPhone Setting

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

This feature might be useful while on developing. But we want to toggle it since we don't want any server informations be exposed to end users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the worklightSettings options is set to "false" in application-descriptor.xml and re-build your project in Worklight Studio followed by a build in Xcode.

If you still see the application settings entry in iOS's Settings.app then select the Clean option in Xcode and run again (in Xcode). This should make the entry go away.